# responsive navigation bar without java script

Tags: html

I have a really simple navigation bar that I would like to be made responsive when in

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
```

There is no exact way it should be, just the simplest form that I could make it responsive without using Java Script.

Has anyone got any ideas or advice?

```
    <nav class="navigation">
  <p>
    <a href="#home"> Home</a> |
    <a href="#home1">home1</a> |
    <a href="#home2"> home2</a> |
    <a href="#home3"> home3</a> |
    <a href="#home4"> home4</a> |
    <a href="#home5"> home6</a>
  </p>
</nav>

.navigation {
 text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  }

 a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#800080;
}

 a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#ffffff;
 background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: you can use input checkbox and label for toggle bar to make responsive without js

Comment: @NIKHILCHANDRAROY is there any code i could look at for this? When any larger than the media query, the nav bar must stay as it is

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that can do your job

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
/* header */
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #B71C1C;
}
.brand {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 5%;
  color: #fff;
}
/* Navigation */
.menu {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
.menu ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
.menu ul a {
  width: 20%;
  height: inherit;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu ul a:hover {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
#menuToggle {
  display: none;
}
.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}
/* navigation < 768px*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
  }
  .menu ul {
      display: block;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s;
      -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s;
      -o-transition: max-height 0.3s;
      transition: max-height 0.3s;
  }
  .menu ul a {
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: #B71C1C;
      padding: 10px 0px 10px 5%;
      border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  }
  .menu-icon {
      width: 100px;
      height: inherit;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0;
      line-height: 60px;
  }
  #menuToggle:checked ~ ul {
      max-height: 350px;
  }
  .menu-icon i {
      font-size: 1.7em;
      color:#fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/4bc5e2ae78.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Responsive Nav</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <figure class="brand">Your Logo</figure>
        <nav class="menu">
            <input type="checkbox" id="menuToggle">
            <label for="menuToggle" class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></label>
            <ul>
                <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Services</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>FAQ's</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Contacts</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: click the arrow up button to make the answer correct and helpfull ..